# How to determine dynamic assembly dependencies on mono framework

Tags: c#, mono

Is there a way to determine all possible dynamically loaded assemblies without manually running through every line of code in the project?

We are running application which utilizes mono. In the code a function is called in which mono uses Assembly.LoadFrom to dynamically load an assembly from mono's GAC. This assembly is not included initially and causes an error. Mono utilized mscorlib assembly to include the assembly.

Comment: Hook into the [AppDomain.AssemblyLoad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload(v=vs.110).aspx) Event and see if you get what you were looking for

Comment: We're trying to determine what will be loaded in dynamically without running through the code. You would have to run the program to use the AppDomain.AssemblyLoad event, correct?

Comment: Dynamic implies that it happens at runtime. Either run it or search the code.

Comment: So are you saying there is no way to predetermine dynamic assembly dependencies without running through every possible sequence scenario in a large project?

Comment: Generally this is correct, but if you happen to know where those dependencies are loaded from you may be able to trace all code paths and find out what will be loaded without executing. If you‘re talking about indirect dependencies (dep. of dep.) and 3rd Party dependencies then you will likely not be able to find all of them. They might even differ depending on the machine and OS they are running on